# What is the command line approach to download a bunch of jars using maven without POM?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am using maven and trying to download a bunch of jars.
I donot want to generate the POM file so i am using the below command

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=<group>:<artifact-name>:<version> -DoutputDirectory=./localdirectory
```

How can i use a similar command in maven to download a bunch of artifacts without the POM file?
Any examples using *artifactItems* would help
The below code snippet does not work

```
mvn dependency:copy -DartifactItems='com.google.guava:guava:18.0','com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3' -DoutputDirectory=./localdirectory
```

Comment: Create a pom file which container your needed dependencies as entries in dependencies and than simply `mvn package` and everything will be downloaded... without manually calling several times complicated command line calls... And what is the problem with creating a pom file? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: We are downloading dependencies for sonatype-iq to scan. 
We do not want to generate a pom or gradle file programatically hence looking out for a solution that can download jars directly.

Comment: To be honest I'm confused on one hand you telling not to use a pom (maven)/ gradle file while you can download file directly. On the other hand your examples using Maven command (via plugin goal) to download files? So writing a pom file will summarize them in a single file and use Maven to let download all files.. much easier. If you really will download files directly (I don't understand why) you have to use either curl or wget instead... Furthermore what does `The below code snippet does not work` mean? output ? error messages etc?